# Unable to instantiate activity componentInfo, Activity declared in Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I was adding the Google Cloud Messaging service to my App and altered my manifest file. I get the following StackTrace.

```
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.phptest/com.example.phptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.phptest.MainActivity
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.phptest.MainActivity
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
02-27 18:58:11.282: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.phptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-configuration />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.phptest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.phptest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.phptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.phptest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.phptest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import com.example.phptest.DeviceLogin.LoginReply;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoginReply {

    String TAG = "Main Activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DeviceLogin d = new DeviceLogin(this);
        d.execute("xxxx","12345");

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, GCMIntentService.senderId);
        } else {
          Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public static String makeCall(String scriptName) {
        String address = "http://10.0.2.2/" + scriptName + ".php";

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = "";
            // Read response until the end
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }

            // Return full string
            System.out.println("TOTAL: " + total.toString());

            return total.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "empty";
    }

    public void onDevicesDownloaded(String login) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `MainActivity` is not in the package `com.example.phptest`?

Comment: Please post MainActivity and consider cleaning your project if it starts with `package com.example.phptest;`. (Please post LogCats in a code block since quote blocks don't respect line breaks and that makes it harder to read.)

Comment: Updated with MainActivity !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to clean project, D'oh! xD

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Android apps get finicky when the full path is specified in the name attribute unless the package the class is in differs from the one you specify at the top of the manifest file. Try changing it to just ".MainActivity" and see if that makes it happy.